# Full screen an image inside a tableviewcell when tapped Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want my image that is inside my table view cell to be full screened when tapped as prompted by a uigesturerecognizer.

The problem is that my didSelectRowAt func does not recognize the `postedimage`identifier.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'postedImage'

How do I get around this issue?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if let imageData = data {

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                cell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }

        }

    }

    cell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")

    return cell
}

func removeImage() {

    let imageView = (self.view.viewWithTag(100)! as! UIImageView)
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func addImageViewWithImage(image: UIImage) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    imageView.image! = image
    imageView.tag = 100

    let dismissTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.removeImage))
    dismissTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.addImageViewWithImage(image: postedImage[indexPath.row])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you should first check and change the call in didSelect
>   function from:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.addImageViewWithImage(image: postedImage[indexPath.row])
}
```

> to

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    self.addImageViewWithImage(image: cell.postedImage.image)
}
```

Now, your **addImageViewWithImage** will accept the image from the ImageView that is contained in the cell.

Comment: share more info if this doesn't help.

Comment: This allows me to open up the image, but when I tap again to close the image goes to the next image in the array.
Also I forgot to mention that `imageView.image! = image` should be `imageView.image = image`.

Comment: @JackRichards  that is happening because on tapping your didselect method is triggered again as it has priority over the tap gesture. You will have to added a different logic which basically checks if image is open and if so then close the image or whatever that you want to do. Maybe use some flags.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I set of booleans `imageFullscreen = false` and then changed it when the overide func was called but that didn't help. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Yes something like that..use a Boolean and in your didselect method put a check based on that. If imageFullscreen == true call the removeImage method else addImageViewWithImage

Comment: You can set imageFullscreen = true in addImageViewWithImage and set it to false in the removeImage()

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageSliderCollectionViewCell
    self.imageTapped(image: cell.problemImage.image!)
}

func imageTapped(image:UIImage){
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not using an array. It seems like postedImage is an `UIImageView`. So it will not work. You need to use an array.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4**  - TableView Cell Selected

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
    self.imageTapped(image: cell.productImageView.image!)
}

func imageTapped(image:UIImage){
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissFullscreenImage(_:)))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```